# What is the probability of choosing a 4-digit number that starts with 1 or 2, and has at least 3 of the same digit?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

This is a question that I haven’t been able to solve!

Some more information:

- The four digit number must start with either 1 or 2.
- I’ve assumed that combinations is required, as the order of the final three digits chosen doesn’t matter. For example, the number 2322 has three 2s, and so does 2223. Hence they are the same combination of 4 digits, (three 2s, one 3).
- The digits can repeat as many times as needed. The only obvious restriction is that the 4-digit number must start with 1 or 2.
- To find the probably, all the favourable outcomes (the number of 4-digit number combinations that start with 1 or 2, that have at least 3 of the same digit), must be divided by the total amount of 4-digit number combinations.
- The range of 4-digit numbers is between 1000 and 9999, as a 4-digit number cannot start with 0. (0999 cannot occur, 0023 cannot either…)
- To be considered a favourable outcome, the digit must repeat 3 or 4 times in the 4-digit number combination.

I’ve had a go:

By hand, I wrote every different 4-digit number combination that starts with 1 or 2, that has at least 3 of the same digit. There were 36 different combinations, although this may be incorrect due to technique used.

I assumed the answer would be 36 divided by the total number of different 4-digit number combinations.

I don’t know how to find these values, though.

How would you solve this?

Comment: It is not correct.  I am not sure what your $385$ number represents.  There are $4 \times 9 =36$ four-digit numbers starting with $1$ which have exactly three digits the same, such as $1000,1119,1181,1711$, and another $36$ starting with $2$.  Then there are $1111$ and $2222$.  Compare that to the $9000$  four-digit numbers

Comment: Alright, so 74 over 9000? Thank you for your help.

Comment: That depends on what the question is actually asking

Comment: "*By hand, I wrote every different ____*"  You should avoid that whenever possible.  The whole point of a course in combinatorics is to learn how to count *without* brute force like this.

Comment: My comment on 385 was derived from research - most likely the source of error. I just don’t understand why, although 74 considers all different combinations of numbers that satisfy the criteria, it is divided by the total amount of permutations possible within the number range - shouldn't the total number of different 4-digit combinations of numbers be the denominator? Not the best conceptually, I’m afraid. Could you explain?

Comment: Agreed, the methodical counting was my only option since I was stuck. Hoping to solve through proper combinations though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I interpret the question:  We pick one of the integers from $1000,1001,1002,1003,\dots,9999$ uniformly at random.  There are $9\times 10^3 = 9000$ of these numbers (*seen by basic application of rule of product, nine options for the first digit, ten options for the second digit and so on... or by common knowledge of numbers*).  We ask what the probability is that the number we picked happens to have a starting digit of $1$ or $2$ and happens to have exactly three identical digits or exactly four identical digits.

Since we are dealing with uniform probability here, we may simply find the count of desired outcomes and divide by 9000 which is the total number of possible outcomes.  (*N.B. this approach of dividing good outcomes over total outcomes is* **only** *valid in such scenarios where we deal with a uniform distribution and is in general not going to give the correct answer*).

Counting the desired outcomes, break into cases based on whether there are exactly three identical or exactly four identical numbers.

- (3 identical numbers) Pick the first digit.  It is either a $1$ or a $2$ for a total of two options.  Given such a selection, pick an additional digit to appear different from the first for a total of nine options.  Now, decide which of the four positions in the number is the "odd one out", being the digit that is not repeated for a total of four options.

Note, if the first digit was the odd one out that means that the alternate digit is the one that is repeated such as in the example of $2888$.  Alternatively if the first digit was not selected to be the odd one out that means that the first digit was among those repeated such as the example of $2822$

- (4 identical numbers).  Pick the first digit, there are two options.  All digits are the same.

$$2\cdot 9\cdot 4 + 2=74$$

The final probability then is $$\frac{74}{9000}$$